# Error- Warning, FIREBASE_CONFIG environment variable is missing. Initializing firebase-admin will fail

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

I tried to connect my existing firestore database to Dialogflow fulfillment. The function deployed to Google CLoud Function successfully but I cannot add data to my database. I have tried to change the node version 8 but still failed. Please help me.

**Index.js**

```
'use strict';
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
   

  admin.initializeApp({
   apiKey: "Axxxx",
    authDomain: "/xxxxx.firebaseio.com",
    databaseURL: "https:/xxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "mxxxxx8",
    storageBucket: "xxxxx.com",
  });

  const functions = require('firebase-functions');
  const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true};
  var db = admin.firestore();
  admin.firestore().settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });
 
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements
 
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
 
  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }
 
  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }
  

  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.2.0",
    "firebase-admin": "~7.1.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.2.1",
    "dialogflow": "^0.6.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.5.0"
  }
```

Comment: Never mind, I found the answer. I made new google cloud project from my current firebase project.

Comment: If you're done with this question and it's no longer relevant, simply delete it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is upgrade your Firebase project plan to Blaze Plan. Then make a new Dialogflow agent under that Firebase project.

Answer (score 0):

Your Firebase initialization seems wrong. Here's how you should do it:

```
.
.
.
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
  databaseURL: 'https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com'
});
.
.
.
```

This should work.

Comment: Thank you for your respond .I already try but still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#automatically_populated_environment_variables) it should be like this,

```js
serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccount.json');

const adminConfig = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG);
adminConfig.credential = admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount);
admin.initializeApp(adminConfig);
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I already found the solution

Comment: Please consider adding the solution to your issue as an answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer