# How to use firebase admin SDK in local Node.js scripts?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm trying to use the firebase admin sdk in a local node.js script file (outside of firebase-functions) in order to preform some auth and firestore operations.

But I get this error:

`{"severity":"WARNING","message":"Warning, FIREBASE_CONFIG and GCLOUD_PROJECT environment variables are missing. Initializing firebase-admin will fail"}`

`Error: Failed to determine project ID: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal. Error code: ENOTFOUND`

Admin SDK initialization:

```js
const admin = await import('firebase-admin');
const serviceKey = require('path/to/serviceKey.json');
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceKey),
    databaseURL: 'https://{project}.firebaseio.com',
});
```

All the questions I've found on this error are regarding running firebase-functions locally, but I'm not trying to use firebase-functions, I'm only trying to use admin.auth and admin.firestore locally.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

It works with the codes below based on this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#authenticate-with-admin-privileges):

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceKey = require('./path/to/serviceKey.json');
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceKey),
    databaseURL: 'https://{project}.firebaseio.com'
});
```

I also saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65084616/8753991), creating new Google Cloud project from current Firebase project and upgrading Firebase project plan to Blaze Plan fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer John. But that code does exactly the same thing as the code piece I wrote. Also, I'm already on the blaze plan.

Comment: can you show the whole code or how we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: Is `await import` and `require` the same? I'm getting error if I'm using your `await import`, it seems that it will depend on the functionality of your apps. I'll update my answer once you update your question with reproducible codes.